# How do I set up a driver that will be effected by an object location and also changes based on that location

Tags: drivers

So I want to a driver that will animate a shape key as another object moves along the y axis. But at a certain point, lets say past 6 units, I want the shape key to decrease instead.
How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula:

```
max( 0, 1 - abs(y - 6) / 6)
```

- `max` is used to stay above 0
- `abs(y - 6)` is centered around 6, between 0 and 6 for y between 0 and 12
- `abs(y - 6) / 6`, between 0 and 1

[image]

[image]

Comment: I followed what you did, but I got ERROR: Invalid Python expression ?

Comment: is the name of the variable correct? "var" is default and I named it "y" here.

Comment: I'm not sure, what I did wrong, but I just copied and pasted it instead and it worked XD
Thank you so much!

Comment: If ok, consider validating the answer.

Comment: So, I've run into another problem. Is there a way to achieve this same effect with using a center. Basically, I need the shape key to ramp up more slowly at the beginning, and when the object reaches it's point, it should rapidly decrease more than the beginning.

Comment: can use this kind of formula `max(0,1 - abs(y-6)/6) if y < 6 else max(0,1 - abs(y-6)/3)` above 6 will decrease twice faster.